# Integrating 2 patterns together

Tags: java

```
PrintWriter sentimentText = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\markc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TwitterTest\\src\\text\\sentimentText.txt");
        Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("https\\S*");
        Pattern linkPattern2 = Pattern.compile("@\\S*");
        for (int i = 0; i < tweetsArray.size(); i++) {

            sentimentText.println(linkPattern.matcher(tweets.get(i).getText()).replaceAll(""));
            sentimentText.println(linkPattern2.matcher(tweets.get(i).getText()).replaceAll(""));

        }
        sentimentText.close();
```

I have a text file that contains words starting with "@" and words starting with "https", I have used a Pattern to remove these words. Using just one of the Patterns work by itself, but if I use both of them together they have no affect.

Any idea of how I can integerate both of the patterns together?

Comment: You have to assign the string returned by the first call to `replaceAll("")` to a variable and then match that string with your second pattern and call `replaceAll("")`. The method `replaceAll(...)` does not alter the string instance that invokes it, it returns a new string, due to Java strings being immutable.

Comment: try `Pattern.compile("(https|@)\\S*")`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`(https|@)\\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/VwaqtK/1) to combine your regex into a group using `|` or

`(https|@)\\S*` match either `https` or `@` character

`\\S*` : match zero or more non-space characters

so use `Pattern.compile("(https|@)\\S*")`